# how to pass string as a function parameter

Tags: c

I am trying to create a function that gets arguments similar to command line arguments. To do this I want to pass a string to my function, but I am getting a segmentation fault (core dumped).

Here is my attempt in the function hello shown below,

```
int hello(int argc, char **argv)                                             
{                                                                               
    int i=0;                                                                        
    printf("%d\n", argc);                                                                                                                               
    for(i=0; i<argc; i++)                                                                
        printf("%s\n", argv[i]);                                                           
    return 0;                                                                   
}
```

which I call from main,

```
int main ()                                                 
{                                                                                                                                          
    hello(3, "i am fine");                             
    return 0;                                                                       
}
```

I want to get

```
i
am
fine
```

but getting segmentation fault instead.

Comment: Hello and welcome. What are you trying to do, exactly? Why do you expect that result? Why 5? Please, explain yourself a bit better.

Comment: You are passing `char *` instead of `char **` and passing a nonsense `argc` value.

Comment: You are passing a `char *` to `hello`, but it is expecting a `char **`. It's not surprising it doesn't work.

Comment: @Sheik In any case the string literal  "i am fine" is one object

Comment: `"i am fine"` is a string literal, i.e. `char*`, a pointer to the first char in a sequence of chars, terminated by a char with value `0`. `char **argv` is an array of such things.

Comment: @Sheik I wonder what are the 5 elements that  the string literal "i am fine" contains?:) Why are you expecting the output i
am
fine

Comment: sorry Federico for the unclear question..thats 3 and not 5..i don't know how to edit..thats why i left as it is...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `hello(5,"i am fine");` in main.c, one of three things should be true:

- You compiled without (many) warning messages enabled in your compiler. If so, turn on warning messages in your compiler.
- The compiler warns you that `hello` is not declared (and perhaps that it assumes a declaration/type for it). If so, insert a declaration of `hello` in main.c (or put it in a header named hello.h and insert `#include <hello.h>` in main.c).
- main.c contains code you did not show us in the question, either a declaration of `hello` or an include of a header file, and the declaration of `hello` in main.c or the header file differs from its definition in hello.c. If so, show the full code in the question.

Once you fix the problems above, there should be a declaration of `hello` in main.c (explicitly or included in a header file) that matches its definition in hello.c:

```
int hello(int argc, char *argv[]);
```

Once that declaration is in main.c, the compiler should warn you that the call `hello(5,"i am fine");` does not match the declaration. This is because `"i am fine"` is an array of characters and, when used in this way, is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element. So the argument passed is a pointer to a `char`, also called a `char *`. But the parameter is a `char **`.

So you need to pass a `char **`. An easy way to do this is to make an array of `char *`:

```
char *Arguments[] = { "i am fine" };
```

Then you can pass the array to `hello`:

```
hello(1, Arguments);
```

As with the array of `char`, this array of `char *` will be automatically converted to a pointer to its first argument, so a `char **` will be passed.

Also note that I changed `5` to `1`. The first argument is the number of strings pointed to by the second argument, and you are passing only one string.

To pass five strings, you should have five strings in the array, and, to match how the arguments to `main` are specified, there should be an additional element in the array that is a null pointer:

```
char *Arguments[] = { "i am fine", "two", "three", "four", "five", 0 };
hello(5, Arguments);
```

After you have that working, you could use a compound literal instead of a named array. A compound literal is a way of creating an object in an expression, and it uses a type name in parentheses followed by values for the object in braces:

```
hello(5, (char *[]) { "i am fine", "two", "three", "four", "five", 0 });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Eric..I got what i want actually from your answer..and sorry for the unclear question...

Answer (score 0):

In your code you call function *hello* with a string instead of an array of strings. Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LEN(arr) (sizeof (arr) / sizeof (arr)[0])

void hello(int argc, const char **argv)
{
    int i = 0;
    printf("%d\n", argc);
    for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
    }
}


int main(void)
{
    const char *args[] = {"i", "am", "fine"};

    hello(LEN(args), args);
    return 0;
}
```

I have also added a `const` qualifier to indicate that the strings will not be modified.